# timeout without killing process in bash

Tags: linux, bash, kill, timeout

I have a main script that I'm running, and from it I have a second "slow process" I want to kick off, and "do something" in the main script if it doesn't complete in the time limit -- depending on if it completed or not. N.B. If the "slow process" finishes before my time limit, I don't want to have to wait an entire time limit.

I want the "slow process" to keep going so I can gather stats and forensics about it's performance.

I've looked into using [timeout](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout), however it will kill my script when finished.

Suppose this simplified example.

**main.sh**

```
result=`timeout 3 ./slowprocess.sh`
if [ "$result" = "Complete" ]
then
 echo "Cool it completed, do stuff..."
else
 echo "It didn't complete, do something else..."
fi
```

**slowprocess.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
start=`date +%s`
sleep 5
end=`date +%s`
total=`expr $end - $start`
echo $total >> /tmp/performance.log
echo "Complete"
```

Here, it uses timeout -- so the script dies, so nothing winds up in `/tmp/performance.log` -- I want `slowprocess.sh` to complete, but, I want `main.sh` to go onto its next step even if it doesn't finish in the 3 seconds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With ksh/bash/zsh:

```
{
  (./slowprocess.sh >&3 3>&-; echo "$?") |
    if read -t 3 status; then
      echo "Cool it completed with status $status, do stuff..."
    else
      echo "It didn't complete, do something else..."
    fi
} 3>&1
```

We duplicate the original stdout onto fd 3 (`3>&1`) so we can restore it for `slowprocess.sh` (`>&3`), while stdout for the rest of the `(...)` subshell goes to the pipe to `read -t 3`.

Alternatively, if you want to use `timeout` (here assuming GNU `timeout`):

```
timeout --foreground 3 sh -c './slowprocess.sh;exit'
```

would avoid `slowprocess.sh` being killed (the `;exit` is necessary for `sh` implementations that optimise by executing the last command in the shell process).

Comment: Could you add a short explanation of the code? Thanks.

Comment: @afuna, see edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using only ubiquitous shell tools.

This should be easily done by forking the slow process and a `sleep` in the background and waiting for the first to finish, except that the `wait` shell builtin waits for *all* jobs to finish rather than only for the first one.

So instead, fork the slow process and a `sleep` in the background, have them both report their status through a pipe, and read the first status that comes out of the pipe.

```
fifo=$(mktemp -u)  # if not on Linux, adapt to what your OS provides
mkfifo -m 600 "$fifo"
{ ./slowprocess.sh; echo z >"$fifo"; } &
sh -c 'sleep 3; echo a' >"$fifo" &
sleep_pgid=$!
read status <$fifo
case $status in
  a) echo "That process is taking a long time"; read ignored <$fifo;;
  z) echo "Done already"; kill -INT -$sleep_pgid;;
esac
rm "$fifo"
```

Comment: That `mktemp` invocation is not portable (won't work on BSDs for instance where you need to specify the template)

Comment: pgids are created only in interactive shells. In scripts, you'd need `set -m`.

Comment: With `bash`, you need quotes around variables in redirected files as well (`> "$fifo"`)

Comment: You may want to set the `umask` to `077` to avoid someone interfering with your fifo.

Comment: As a note (probably not an issue to the OP), asynchronous processes have their stdin redirected from `/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is blocking in the `slowprocess.sh` could be backgrounded so that it can continue even after the timeout.

Also you might be able to use a `signal` from `timeout` back to your `main.sh`. See the man page for `timeout`.

*excerpt from `timeout` info page*

```
`-s SIGNAL'
`--signal=SIGNAL'
     Send this SIGNAL to COMMAND on timeout, rather than the default
     `TERM' signal. SIGNAL may be a name like `HUP' or a number. Also
     see *Note Signal specifications::.
```

You'd have to trap for this signal inside of `main.sh`.

Also `timeout` returns different statuses for different types of failures. You might be able to make use of these as well:

```
   Exit status:

     124 if COMMAND times out
     125 if `timeout' itself fails
     126 if COMMAND is found but cannot be invoked
     127 if COMMAND cannot be found
     the exit status of COMMAND otherwise
```

These are present in the variable `$?`, after the `timeout ...` line runs.

Comment: I don't think that can work. If the slow process is backgrounded then `timeout` won't see whether it's still running. If `timeout` doesn't kill the process, then it doesn't return.

Comment: @Gilles - yeah it was a loosely thought out collection of "possible" solutions, I didn't have the time to provide full solutions, so I just provided some ideas, but I agree they weren't very well vetted, and probably won't end up panning out. My initial thought was that what he wanted wasn't possible. Felt a bit like the OP wanted to have his/her cake and eat it too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach that is fairly simple, though it produces some extraneous job control output:  start a background process "sleep nnn" then use "wait -n" to wait for the first of the sleep process and the process you're monitoring.  Here's a somewhat clumsy example of the technique (with "set -o notify" immediate notifications):

```
$ (for I in $(seq 10); do sleep 1; echo $I ; done) & \
more> J1=$! ; \
more> sleep 5 & \
more> J2=$! ; \
more> time wait -n $J1 $J2
[1] 288160
[2] 288161
1
2
3
4
[2]+  Done                    sleep 5

real    0m5.006s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.004s
$ 5
6
7
8
9
10
[1]+  Done                    ( for I in $(seq 10);
do
sleep 1; echo $I;
done )
$

$ (for I in $(seq 3); do sleep 1; echo $I ; done) & \
more> J1=$! ; \
more> sleep 5 & \
more> J2=$! ; \
more> time wait -n $J1 $J2
[1] 288256
[2] 288257
1
2
3
[1]-  Done                    ( for I in $(seq 3);
do
sleep 1; echo $I;
done )

real    0m3.025s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.015s
$ [2]+  Done                    sleep 5
$
```